# LWJGL input with PS3 controller?

Tags: java, controller, lwjgl, minecraft, jinput

I'm kind of new to LWJGL (I have done some things with it in Minecraft), and I need some help. I want to make a mod for Minecraft where the user could have the option of using their PS3 controller. I have looked for `JInput` tutorials for beginners, and found none. I have also tried looking at how Minecraft handles input with LWJGL, but I couldn't find anything good.

I'm kind of desperate now. Please help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the JInput forum at javagaming.org, there is a sticky there for getting started with JInput that has some tutorials.

LWJGL wraps JInput for controllers, it has it's own code for keyboard and mice, but everything else goes through JInput.

Regarding the PS3 controller, as long as the underlying OS has drivers for it, and exposes it via the normal method (/dev/input/event device for linux, directx for windows etc) then JInput  will see it.

HTH